# CISCO anyconnect issue with WLAN

Tags: cisco-vpn

When I am connected to internet using WLAN, I am successfully able to connect to VPN using CISCO anyconnect secure mobility client but no traffic passes...please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have "Allow Local (Lan) access when using VPN " checked in the settings
[image]

Comment: will try then let u know...I believe I tried that as well....